# Generating electricity: Does wire thickness for magnetic induction matter?

Tags: voltage, power, current, generator, power-generation

I know that the strength of the magnetic field and the speed by which the conductor passes the magnetic field have an effect on magnetic induction for the voltage output on a generator.

I also know that when conducting electricity from a source to and end user that the longer the distance the thicker the wire needs to be or else eddie currents and resistance will cause the wire to overheat (and thus either melt or cause a fire hazard.)

What I want to know is that when building my DIY generator, do I also need to adjust the wire size to the length of wire? Will using a thicker wire or thinner wire make an impact on efficiency of magnetic induction to produce electricity?

For example, if I want to be sure I have a greater voltage output or whatever (with less resistance or impedance,) do I increase the thickness of the wire or decrease the thickness of the wire?

Answer (score 1):

The thickness of a wire directly impacts the resistance per unit length. Resistance (when current flows through it) causes voltage drop. Other than that, the thickness of a wire has no noticeable effect upon the voltage induced in it due to a changing magnetic field.

> if I want to be sure I have a greater voltage output or whatever (with less resistance or impedence), do I increase the thickness of the wire or decrease the thickness of the wire?

Current flowing through a resistance causes a) a voltage drop, and b) heat. Neither of these things are usually wanted in a device such as a generator. Therefore your wire should be thick enough to handle the expected current with minimal, or at least acceptable, resistance. A thicker wire will have lower resistance.

It should be noted that, as is often the case, there are diminishing returns from ever increasing the thickness of the wire. If the efficiency of your device is already, say 95%, it may or may not be worth it to increase the thickness of your wire to increase your efficiency to 96%. Besides the fact copper costs money, thicker wire also adds bulk. When wires get too bulky to fit in the space that is allotted to them, one may need to use a larger structure to hold those wires. In transformers, for example, once one gets to the point where the number of turns of wire can no longer fit in the "window" within a core, one has to shift to a larger core. So, use wire that is thick enough to handle your current with acceptable losses, but don't go overboard, because the payoff may be less than the cost.

On a side note, you wrote:

> I also know that when conducting electricity from a source to and end use that the longer the distance the more thicker the wire needs to be or else eddie currents and resistance will cause the wire to overheat (and thus either melt or cause a fire hazard).

Wire size has nothing to do with eddy currents, and you may want to use wire that is larger than the minimum needed to prevent fire. Or not. It depends upon the losses in your wire, and whether they are acceptable.

Comment: You are correct about the eddy currents. That applies to a magnetic field passing a conductive material. It is why there are laminated metal cores in motors... to reduce the effect of eddy currents and the core overheating. Now I have some follow up questions to your estute contribution:

How would I go about calculating a wire sufficiently thick enough to handle the expected current with minimal, or at least acceptable, resistance?

How would I go about calculating the diminishing returns from ever increasing the thickness of the wire?

Comment: Will it be necessary to have a laminated metal core to these coils, or is that irrelevatant?

Also, do you have the simple arithmatic math or Versor Algebraic equastions for these? If not, I'll take the normal equations used to calculate a given desired design outcome if you have them handy. But please avoid advance mathematics or complex calculus if not absolutely necessary. Otherwise I'll take it if there is no other way around it.

Comment: There is a chart on [this page](http://www.magnetwire.biz/magnet_wire_current.html) that gives resistance and max current for various size magnet wire (which is probably what you want for a generator). There are different types of generators. Some are "induction machines", constructed similar to induction motors. They generally have laminated iron cores. The "wires" in the rotor are often made by pouring liquid aluminum into cavities in the core. Stator wires are usually regular copper wire.

Comment: Yes, I have heard the term before, "induction motor". I do not know anything about them though. I will look into the things you suggest. Thank you for your contributions. Off to work now.

Answer (score 0):

A longer wire has more resistance.  A plumper wire has less resistance.

The amount of voltage you will be able to generate will be proportional to the field strength and the number of turns(loops) of wire in your coil.

Thinner wire allows you to have more turns in the same volume of coil, but more turns means extra wire length, which means more resistance, which will increase your losses.  Essentially thinner wire allows more voltage, but less current.

Thicker wire means you can fit less turns in the same volume, which means less resistance and less losses for the same amount of current, but less induced voltage, so thicker wire allows less voltage but more current.

Before you go thinking of making your coil larger to get more turns of thicker wire, you need a stronger field to penetrate a thicker coil, or it will do more harm than good and waste material.

You can find the length of a single turn and use resistance and size of different wire gauges to calculate how many turns and how much resistance you had for different wire sizes easily enough, but this will only get you so far.  To really figure things out ahead of time you use advanced math to predict your field strength to estimate output current and voltage.

Every size of wire has a limit to how much current can flow on it without overheating and will heat up proportional to I\$^2\$R, where I is current and R is resistance.

Without advanced math skills, the best thing to do is experiment.

If you haven't already, learn current, voltage, resistance, series and parallel circuits, Ohm's Law, Watt's Law, Resistance in series and in parallel, Kirchhoff's Laws.  That small list of formulas will let you calculate basic voltage/power/resistance/current calculations like figuring out wire size.  Then learn about capacitance and inductance if you're not sick of it by then.  You can also learn about magnetics and use tools like Finite Element Magnetic Modeller(free) to simulate things and somewhat simplify your design process.  It increases the amount you can figure out about a magnetic system at whatever skill level you're at, but the only way to use it properly is higher math and programming.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I completely understand your formula of current squared times resistance. However, can you provide the exact step by step breakdown of how I would go about making the appropriate design of a given desired optimum outcome? Please include the mathematics. If you can translate those mathematics to basic arithmatic, or versor algebra, that would be optimum. If not, I'll take the advanced mathematics.

Comment: I am looking for a good optimized balance between both votage and current for general use power applications (computer, household, and power tool stuff). How would I go about calculating a wire sufficiently thick enough to handle the expected current with minimal, or at least acceptable, resistance? How would I go about calculating the diminishing returns from ever increasing the thickness of the wire?

Comment: If you already have the math skills, it's just a matter of looking up the formulas and constructing the correct models.  You need more than just algebra so there is no basic arithmetic version you can do.  I have enough education to know in general what techniques are used, but not enough to execute or explain them myself.  Motor design has many compromises and trade offs.  One of my projects right now is a generator design.  My first design was nicely powerful but had issues with cogging torque.  My second one will be better.  I needed some expensive tools to build it.

Comment: You should look at the different types of motor first, and figure out which type you think you have the mechanical skills to build.  You may be able to use parts from salvaged motors.  Learn about magnetic fields so you can figure out how much iron to use and where in your design, and if it has to be special type, like silicon steel laminate.  It's possible to build a motor without iron or with less iron, but there are extra challenges, so you might want to learn about halbach arrays and axial flux motors if that interests you.

Comment: Do you already own a DC battery bank or solar system?  How are you planning to power this generator?  If it generates significant amounts of energy it will be large and expensive.  You're just going to have to take your best guess for wire size, but you can consider using a larger number of coils in your wiring so you can put them in parallel or series to give you options on output voltage/current.  You should try making several small generators for practice before you try to build a big one.

Comment: For significant amounts of power, the copper and magnet cost could be quite high.

Comment: Thanks for that KH. Good luck on your generator venture. Yes, that cogging issue can be a bit troublesome to overcome, it is one thing that I'll have to deal with myself in my design. I already know about the Halbach array, and I expect to incorporate it in my design. I did not know about the axial flux.

Comment: I have been studying electrodynamics and the field effects of magnets. I am not to Calculus yet, I have mathematics through to Trigonometry, but have been out of it for several years, so I am having to relearn a lot. But according to Dr. Eric Dollard HonPhD (EE), all of electical engineering principles can be done with Versor Algebra. I'm not there yet.

Comment: RE: Turning the generator. The mechanics of rotational electric generators all rely on magnetic induction, regardless of the input energy system; like wind, heat, steam, nuclear, etc. There are many that are now in the public domain, but were not before they were released to the public. The exact details of each of these systems before that time were proprietary, and thus is the condition of my input rotational energy system. Of course small and expiramental is where it is at right now. The ideal situation is if I had a multiphysics software to work with, but it's a bit beyond me for now.

Comment: He's probably referring to individual principles and elements.  You use calculus and linear algebra to evaluate complicated systems of elements without spending years doing math.  If you want to, say, design a generator with a predictable(and controllable) output voltage at a specific frequency and choose your output current and voltage ahead of time, the comparisons you need to make are so complicated that the only sensible way is to use higher maths or better yet learn enough programming to program a computer to do the calculation for you.

Comment: Well without telling anyone what is creating the torque, you can still figure out how much torque is generated at what speed, and whether it is constant or intermittent.  You might want to go watch some homemade generator videos on youtube.

Comment: "programming to program a computer to do the calculation for you." That would be the "MatLab" Software. One thing that is on the roster to eventually learn in my course curriculum. Thank you for your comments KH. Good luck on your generator. If you have any further ideas on how this project can proceed, of course you can leave them. I now need to go and sign off. Saludos!

Comment: I will look into the things you suggest in your updated comment. Thank you for your contributions. Off to work now.

Comment: I searched the Internet for "Finite Element Magnetic Modeller", and all it turned up was people mentioning that name in this forum, but nowhere else and no link provided. I tried an abbreviation of that as FEMM, and it turned up "Finite Element Method Magnetics" at https://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yep that's the one.  Sorry I got the name wrong.

Comment: Acknowleged. Thanks! By your recommendation, I will learn more about it and most likely use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more voltage use a stronger magnet or spin it faster.

If you want more current use a stronger magnet (more speed won't help much)

At some strength of magnet the stator will be saturated and increasing the magnetic field will not show much gain.

When winding the stator there's a trade-off between more turns giving more voltage or fewer turns giving more current, you should use enough wire to fill the winding slots (so for fewer turns use thicker wire, or parallel wires).

If you use thinner wire you will loose more energy to the wire's resistance.

So to answer your question yes you should adjust the wire cross-section inversely to the length of the wire so that the slots stay full.  Another approach is to use two wires in parallel instead of a single thicker wire.

Comment: Hello Jasen. Thank you for your answer. I never thought of using "two wires in parallel instead of a single thicker wire." Have you done this already, and if so, what was your results? As for the other two design considerations of stronger magnet and faster spin, it is what I stated as known in my question. I am using a Halbach array to increase the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Motors and transformers and other similar wirewound devices will always be more efficient if the area allocated for the winding is packed as full as possible. So the basic idea is to use the thickest copper wire that still allows you to get the correct number of turns.

If it just barely fits, then it is right. If it fits with lots of extra space, go up one wire size.

This should make sense. Voltage and inductance depend only on number of turns. Resistance depends on length and diameter of wire. You want to minimize resistance for best efficiency.